# Azure SQL SSRS Hybrid Configuration

Tags: ssrs, azure-sql-database, visual-studio

I would like to migrate my existing Visual Studio SSRS Reports to the cloud while keeping my database on-premise.  Any advice on resources for getting started would be greatly appreciated - tutorials, training sites (pluralsight, cbtnuggets, etc).

Thanks in advance